# recognize operation/function with 2 values by result

Tags: types, hex, byte, decimal, bit-manipulation

Updated:

I have some data structure. I have no information what structure it is and how values are stored, but it should contain array of numeric values (integer)

Bytes (in decimal):

```
0 20 13 4 25 0 0 0 54 0 0 0 195 145 23 0 0 195 146 23 0 0 195 168
23 0 0 24 24 0 0 195 168 23 0 0 195 169 23 0 0 116 23 0 0 195 146
23 0 0 195 169 23 0 0 194 186 23 0 0 195 168 23 0 0 24 24 0 0 194
163 23 0 0 116 23 0 0 195 169 23 0 0 195 145 23 0 0 195 146 23 0
0 195 168 23 0 0 0 24 0 0 195 146 23 0 0 194 186 23 0 0 194 186 23
0 0 194 163 23 0 0 194 186 23 0 0 117 23 0 0 46 23 0 0 93 23 0 0
24 24 0 0 23 24 0 0 23 24 0 0 70 24 0 0 0 23 0 0 23 23 0 0 23 23 0
0 47 23 0 0 70 23 0 0 0 23 0 0 116 23 0 0 23 23 0 0 94 23 0 0 46 23
0 0 116 23 0 0 195 146 23 0 0 0 23 0 0 70 23 0 0 93 23 0 0 70 23 0
0 116 23 0 0 194 186 23 0 0 70 22 0 0 70 22 0 0 46 23 0 0 70 23 0
0 93 23 0 0
```

Stored values (without semicolon):

```
6098; 6120; 6168; 6120; 6121; 6004; 6098; 6121; 6074; 6120; 6168; 6051; 6004;
6121; 6097; 6098; 6120; 6144; 6098; 6074; 6074; 6051; 6074; 6005; 5934; 5981;
6168; 6167; 6167; 6214; 5888; 5911; 5911; 5935; 5958; 5888; 6004; 5911; 5982;
5934; 6004; 6098; 5888; 5958; 5981; 5958; 6004; 6074; 5702; 5702; 5934; 5958;
5981
```

**Corrected/Updated:**

1. first 8 bytes (0 20 13 4 25 0 0 0) are used you store the date(when record was created)
   2013-4-25 0:0:0
2. values are stored in 4 bytes in reversed order, so  last 4 bytes 93 23 0 0  should be 0 0 23 93, and then we can shift and OR:

> $res=0;
>   $res=($res << 8 ) | $byte1;
>   $res=($res << 8 ) | $byte2;
>   $res=($res << 8 ) | $byte3;
>   $res=($res << 8 ) | $byte4;

then we get the correct result 5981, this also works with other values, except some cases when extra byte appears, it is either 194 or 195

> if extra byte is 194 and we ignore it the result will be still correct, but if it is 195, then the result is wrong.

what are 194,195 bytes used for?

**Problem solved!**
Bytes were stored as string, and during the reading the wrong encoding was used.
Converted raw string to ISO-8859-1, then splitted it into bytes (no 194,195 appeared), then simply read by 4 bytes in reversed order.

**Special thanks to Paul R**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a shift and OR:

```
result = (byte_2 << 8) | byte_1;
```

It's easier to see if you look at the values in hex:

```
byte1 =       01011101 =   93 =   0x5d
byte2 =       00010111 =   23 =   0x17
result = 1011101011101 = 5981 = 0x175d
```

Comment: you are right, thank you

however, in some cases it uses 3 bytes to store the value, I added the whole row for more info